# How to ignore exact duplicate rows, but having duplicates in the columns is ok?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a large dataset with a list of names and each "fruit" they ate each day. I'd like to ignore rows with exact duplicates across the entire row, but still keep multiple rows of the same name if there are multiple fruit. I also only want to see names if they ate at least 2 unique fruits.

As you can see in the example below, john is left out because he only ate 1 type of fruit, while bob and matt had a row removed because of a dupilcate. I hope this makes sense and thanks for the help!

Before:

```
 name  | fruit
-------+---------
bob    |   apple
bob    |   apple
bob    |   banana
john   |   apple
john   |   apple
matt   |   pear
matt   |   orange
matt   |   orange
```

After:

```
name   | fruit
-------+---------
bob    |   apple
bob    |   banana
matt   |   pear
matt   |   orange
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
select distinct name, fruit
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.fruit <> t.fruit);
```

Comment: Why the downvote, it's a valid answer to the question?

Comment: Maybe because it lacks an explanation?

Comment: Could you explain where t2 comes from? A subquery I assume but what should that include?

Comment: @Jason . . . `t2` is a column alias for your table.